# does javac sourcepath work?

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to use javac -sourcepath but I feeling I am doing something really stupid.

```
[leoks@x ~]$ pwd
/home/leoks

[leoks@x ~]$ /opt/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac -sourcepath /home/leoks/EclipseIndigo/workspace2/sand/src/ Hello.java
javac: file not found: Hello.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

[leoks@x ~]$ /opt/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac             /home/leoks/EclipseIndigo/workspace2/sand/src/Hello.java

[leoks@x ~]$ /opt/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac -help
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
(...)
-sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
```

I know nobody uses this option, but is this option broken? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Has Hello.java a `package` statement ?

Comment: no. that's why the second javac command works

Comment: yes/no. The second will work always, even with package statement.

Comment: Maybe this will help you to understand how class/sourcepath works: http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/miscellaneous_java/Using_CLASSPATH_and_SOURCEPATH.html

Comment: sourcepath is only to solve dependencies? and now I am really confused. The site says "For example, say one has the directory structure: foo/src/TestFoo.java" and then it declares the class into "package com.foo.test". what? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Put your source into a package and try again:

```
[leoks@x ~]$ /opt/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac -sourcepath /home/leoks/EclipseIndigo/workspace2/sand/src/ t/Hello.java
```

It is not good practice to put classes into the `default package`.

Comment: this is surely a nice workaround, but I think I have to read your link once more to understand why it doesn't work using the default package :-)

Comment: Yeah, I really cannot find a good reference right now for this. sourcepath works the same as classpath. Maybe search further for default package ...